# How to catch timeout in blocking socket

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I am trying to make `Blocking UDP socket` (server)

If data doesn't receive, the `socket` will hang forever.

I want to make it to `5 sec timeout.`

Is there any solution?

```
byte[] data = new byte[1024];

socket.Bind(endpoint);         
socket.Blocking = true;

EndPoint tmpRemote = (EndPoint)sender;
while (true)
{
   try
   {
      recv = socket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref tmpRemote);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket class contain ReceiveTimeOut property . You can set any value to this property and catch exception when timeout occurs .
Please check this url : https://www.demo2s.com/csharp/csharp-socket-receivetimeout.html